# Gulp - Target only a files in Subfolders

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-concat

I have a gulpfile watching for changes in a following folder:

```
SCSSSource = '../framework/**/*.scss';
```

This will watch for changes in following example files:

1. `'../framework/styling.scss'` // root folder
2. `'../framework/subfolder1/styling.scss'`
3. `'../framework/subfolder2/styling.scss'`

I would like to exclude all files from a root folder (1.), and leave only a subfolders to be watched. How should i modify `SCSSSource` String, to achieve that?

Full Code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var concat = require('gulp-concat-util');


gulp.task('watch', function(){

  // "./*"  - all in current foler
  // "./**" - all in current foler and subfolders

  // SCSS FILE
  var SCSSPath = '../framework/';
  var SCSSName = '**/*.scss';
  var SCSSSource = SCSSPath + SCSSName;

  function concatSCSS(){
    // concatenate files
    gulp.src(SCSSSource)
    .pipe(concat('_cssfw.scss', {
      process: function(src){
        src = "\n\n\n\/\/ ----------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
              + src;
        return src;
      }
    }))
    .pipe(concat.header('\/\/SCSS Framework\n\n'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSSPath + "./"));
  }

  watch('../framework/**/*.scss', function (info) {
    concatSCSS();
    console.log(info.event + " scss: " + info.history[0].replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''))
  });

  concatSCSS();

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think you could use the glob pattern to exclude the `.scss` files in the root folder, like this:

```
var SCSSSource = SCSSPath + SCSSName;
var exclude = "!../framework/*.scss"
function concatSCSS(){
        // concatenate files
        gulp.src([SCSSSource, exclude])
```

This way you only get the .scss files from the subdirectories

Comment: Agreed, modifying to `var SCSSSource = ['../framework/**/*.scss', '!../framework/*.scss'];` solved it.